# Does a VHDL function have to return a value?

Tags: vhdl

I would like to create a function to write a file via the TEXTIO library. This is quite a simple routine to write naturally, but for clarity of code I would prefer to write it as a function.

I know the typical way of writing a function is as follows

Heading type

```
function my_func(my_arg : my_arg_type) return return_type;
```

Body type

```
function my_func(my_arg : my_arg_type) return return_type is
```

However, if I am not interested in returning anything is there a way to avoid the critical warning -

```
return type is not specified
```

Comment: The difference between a function and a procedure is that functions have return values and procedures not.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 4. Subprograms and packages "Subprograms define algorithms for computing values or exhibiting behavior." ... "There are two forms of subprograms: procedures and functions. A procedure call is a statement; a function call is an expression and returns a value." ... "The definition of a subprogram can be given in two parts: a subprogram declaration defining its calling conventions, and a subprogram body defining its execution."..."The execution of a subprogram body, other than an uninstantiated subprogram body, is invoked by a subprogram call."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. But, you could use a *procedure* instead:

```
procedure my_func (my_arg : my_arg_type) is
```

You can put a procedure in a package:

```
package P is
  procedure my_func (my_arg : my_arg_type);
end package P;

package body P is
  procedure my_func (my_arg : my_arg_type) is
  begin
    // blah blah blah
  end procedure my_func;
end package body P;
```

SystemVerilog has *void functions* which have no return type, but this can't be done using VHDL.

Comment: I did think about using a procedure, however I am compiling this in a package, thus making the use of procedures outside of the package useless (at least to my knowledge) could you suggest any other methods?

Comment: @lewisthegruffalo There's absolutely no reason why you can't put the procedure in a package. You put a procedure in a package in exactly the same way as you would put a function.

Comment: *Does a VHDL function have to return a value?* to which you answer *No* while (9. Expressions 9.1 "An expression is a formula that defines the computation of a value.", a function call is a primary - an expression and 9.3.4 "Execution of the function body results in a value of the type declared to be the result type in the declaration of the invoked function.").  Your "No." is confusing and contradicted by the standard. Contrast this with a procedure call statement (10.7).

Answer (score 2):

No. A function must always return a value of a known type.
You should use a procedure instead.